# How do I give one single data to a whole column in a HTML table?

Tags: html

I am trying to create a table using HTML like this:
[image: the Total column has only one single value that is aligned at the center]

I wrote something like this:

```html
<table>
  <caption>Bill Summary</caption>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Months</th>
    <th colspan="3">Bills</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Total</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Electricity</td>
    <td>Water</td>
    <td>Gas</td>
    <td align="center">9925</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>975</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>1200</td>
    <td>1200</td>
    <td>975</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>1500</td>
    <td>1100</td>
    <td>975</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

But it gives out put like this:
[image: my borders are not the same:(]
**I need to have that one total amount aligned in the center and a border like the first table image**
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The "total value" cell must be on the third row and it must have a `rowspan` of 3.

Comment: @Progman it just shows the Total and the value (9975) at the same row!:(

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use the `rowspan` attribute here as well.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <caption>Bill Summary</caption>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Months</th>
        <th colspan="3">Bills</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Electricity</th>
        <th>Water</th>
        <th>Gas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td>975</td>
        <td rowspan="3">9925</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>1200</td>
        <td>1200</td>
        <td>975</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>March</td>
        <td>1500</td>
        <td>1100</td>
        <td>975</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

move total value to third row and modify like this

```
<td align="center" style="vertical-align: middle" rowspan="3" >9925</td>
```